# looping through OLEDB Source in ssis using SQL query with variable having parameters

Tags: ssis

I have a confuguration table which contains queries in rows like the one below
@user min and max are the date range I am passing through variable, Currently I am looping the queries through foreach loop but when I am passing these queries to the SQL OLEDB source through variable I am getting error saying the query requires two parameters which is not passed, whereas in my package the user:Min and User:Max is already present. Not sure what is the error.

```
"select DISTINCT 
        P.[Project Request SID] AS Attribute1,
        P.[Project Name] AS Attribute2, 
        NULL AS Attribute3, 
        NULL AS Attribute4,
        NULL AS Attribute5,
        NULL AS Attribute6,
        NULL AS Attribute7,
        NULL AS Attribute8,
        NULL AS Attribute9,
        NULL AS Attribute10,
        NULL AS Attribute11,
        NULL AS Attribute12,
        NULL AS Attribute13,
        NULL AS Attribute14,
        NULL AS Attribute15,
        NULL AS Attribute16,
        NULL AS Attribute17,
        NULL AS Attribute18,
        NULL AS Attribute19,
        NULL AS Attribute20
   from [dbesbiods].dbo.vwGCMProjectRequest P
   join [dbesbiods].dbo.vwGCMProjectRequestDate PD
     on p.[Project Request SID]=PD.[Project Request SID]
   join dbesbiods.Reporting.vwContract c
     on convert(nvarchar(20),P.[Contract Id])=convert(nvarchar(20),c.[Contract Id])  
  where 1=1
    and [Project Status] in ('Active','Submitted')
    and c.[Contract Status] not in ('Abandoned','Rejected')
    and P.[Funding Type] in ('Billable-External')
    And PD.[Project Start Date] between '" +@[User::Min] +"'"+" and '"+@[User::Max]+"'"  +"
    and [Project Name] is null"
```

Comment: I guess you're storing the SQL in a variable and use a *Execute SQL Task* with SQLSourceType = Variable, SourceVariable = your-variable. Or your are use the *Execute SQL Task* with an Expression for the SqlStatementSource. In that case the parameter mapping should be empty

Comment: I am pulling this SQL query from a SQL config table and storing it in a variable say A, later in Data flow task, I am using oledb source and selecting sql command from variable. and before execution also I am selecting variable A property (execute expression as true)

Comment: Is it like this: in the DataFlowTask you have an OLEDBSource; therein the `Data access mode` is set to `SQL command from variable` with the variable name equal to `User::A`. When you click on `Preview...`, what do you get? If you get an error message, what is it?

Comment: The error is "command test was not set for the command object"

Comment: What is the data access mode inside OLEDB Source? It should be SQL Command From variable. Aftter this, select the variable from drop down box. (See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d4e6f03-6420-426d-bc31-b84a5ff82d45/quotcommand-text-was-not-set-for-the-command-objectquot?forum=sqlintegrationservices)